# How to create invisible uibuttons on top of specific words in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uitextview, hyperlink

I'm trying to design an app that displays some instructions to a user. I'm displaying these instructions through a UITextView and right now I'm trying to add a feature where the user can click on a specific word and view the definition for it in another view.

The specific words are all going to be coming from an sqlite database.
So my question is: What would be the best way to achieve this?

I was thinking of overlaying invisible UIButtons on top of the words, but I have no idea how to position them on top of the words inside the UITextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what you need would be to use an UIWebView instead of the UITextView. You would convert your instruction text into a HTML file like this one:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <div>This is a dummy text with a <a href="definition://id1234">clickable keyword</a> inside the text</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

When you put the clickable keywords into  tags they become clickable and you can intercept this clicks in the UIWebView's delegate method.

So load your HTML text into an UIWebView:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
webView.delegate = self;
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourdomain.com/text.html"]]];
```

When you assign a delegate to your webview (like in the code snippet above) the following method gets called everytime the UIWebView makes a request. Here you can intercept the clicks on the keywords. I gave the keyword HTML links their own scheme ("definition://") to make the interception a bit easier and more reliable. (You could later have other links in your HTML.)

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
   if ([[request.URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"definition"]) {
      NSString *definitionWordID = [request.URL host];
      NSLog(@"show definition for word with ID: %@", definitionWordID);
      return NO;
   }
   return YES;
}
```

This is how I would implement what you want to achieve. Using HTML has the great advantage that you do not have to worry about the keyword positions inside the text, because you are using HTML links for the keywords. In addition to that using HTML gives you the opportunity to style the text via CSS.

Comment: This is actually quite an elegant solution to my problem! I think i'll head in this direction as it seems like much less work then finding the frames/bounds of specific words in a UITextView. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the best approach, but I'll answer the question as you've asked it:

```
// This assumes you have already determined the frame for the button
// i.e., you know the origin and size of the word in the UITextView
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[btn setFrame:wordFrame];
[textView addSubview:btn];
// Now, you need to also figure out how to handle the user pressing the button
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(wordButtonWasPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

---

Now, for a different suggestion, you might want to create your own UIView subclass, execute custom drawing yourself (which will also implement logic for tracking the location of words) and then implement touch event handling, cross-checking the location of the touch against your list of word locations. I'm not sure which will be better, but if you're talking about adding a ton of UIButtons, you'll probably run into performance issues relatively quickly.

To handle touch events in a custom UIView subclass, look into the following methods:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Comment: I actually have no idea how to determine the frame/bounds of a specific word inside of a UITextView... But once I figure that our, your solution would help me out a lot! Thank you nonetheless!